# Disable other buttons when Record button active

Tags: java, android

I have 4 items in the menu and 1 button Rec / Stop. I want, when the Rec button is active and records, the other 4 items in the menu items are disabled. Please help me.

this is activity_main.xml

```
<ToggleButton
    android:id="@+id/recStop"
    android:layout_width="65dp"
    android:layout_height="65dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
    android:background="@drawable/tbutton"
    android:text=""
    android:textOff=""
    android:textOn="" />
```

this is tbutton.xml

```
<item android:drawable="@drawable/rec"
android:state_checked="false" />

<item android:drawable="@drawable/stop"
android:state_checked="true" />
```

this is MainActivity.java

```
private ToggleButton toggleButton;

toggleButton = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.recStop);

// Button Rec / Stop
toggleButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                                 boolean isChecked) {

        if (isChecked) {
            speech.setRecognitionListener(VoiceRecognitionActivity.this);
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            progressBar.setIndeterminate(true);
            speech.startListening(recognizerIntent);
        } else {
            progressBar.setIndeterminate(false);
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            speech.stopListening();
            speech.destroy();

        }

    }
});
```

this is MainActivity.java

```
// Menu items
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.copy:
        break;
}
switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.share:
        break;
}
switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.clear:
        break;
}
switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.about:
        break;
}
return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: did you try when toggle button ischecked then setEnable(false)  for all other buttons ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside each condition of your `switch...case`, check the status of togglebutton and if its checked avoid further actions in it. Also don't use multiple switch, you must define multiple cases inside it see the code below.

```
switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.copy:
        if(toggleButton.isChecked()) {
             //display warning message
        } else {
             // your regular code here
        }
        break;

    case R.id.share:
        if(toggleButton.isChecked()) {
             //display warning message
        } else {
             // your regular code here
        }
        break;

    case R.id.clear:
        if(toggleButton.isChecked()) {
             //display warning message
        } else {
             // your regular code here
        }

        break;

    case R.id.about:
        if(toggleButton.isChecked()) {
             //display warning message
        } else {
             // your regular code here
        }
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that with this code

```
  switch (item.getItemId()) {
   case R.id.copy:
    if(toggleButton.isChecked()) {
          menu.findItem(R.id.copy).setEnabled(false);
    } else {
         menu.findItem(R.id.copy).setEnabled(true);
    }
    break;

//you do the same for the rest of menu buttons
 }
```